# Importing sqlite data to chrome browser

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome

I have got a .sqlite file which has table definition and data. I want to store this data to chrom broswer and query against it. I tried query it against the physical file but it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use JavaScript and a WebSQL database. See: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/

But importing your file is not that easy because with WebSQL you can't read an sqlite file but WebSql is the only way for storing information via SQL in Chrome.